# Submit executable + input files with qsub to create multiple jobs

Tags: linux, loops, sh, executable, qsub

I have an executable that takes one input file and have been running it like so, submitting as a job to pbs using qsub:

```
qsub -q long path/to/runpp path/to/input.fa
```

I have a script (runpp_multi.sh) to make it run on multiple files in a directory:

```
for i in path/to/input/*.fa ; do path/to/runpp $i ; done
```

These both work fine, but obviously there's a problem if I submit the script that runs on multiple files with qsub:

```
qsub -q long runpp_multi.sh
```

This submits the executable running on all the files as one job. I would like each file to be submitted as a separate job, something like this:

```
for i in path/to/input/*.fa ; do qsub -q long path/to/runpp $i ; done
```

I have seen that -v could be what I'm looking for, but I'm very confused about the syntax, particularly with my case.

Could I get some advice on how to modify my script so that each file in a directory runs with the executable as a separate job? I have too many files to do it manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a [self-extracting archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) with [shar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) (see GNU [sharutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/)) and submit it to `qsub`.